# Ball is jumping unexpectedly in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a game with unity3D that ball is rolling on the ground.

When I set single large ground block, and using Rigidbody.AddForce() in Unity3D. ball is rolling fine.

But if I set multiple small ground blocks, ball is jumping unexpectly on boundary of blocks. Even block size, positions and intervals are exactly matched.

Can I solve this problem?

(I can't freeze position Y of ball. because ball needs gravity.)

[image]

-edited-

Here is my code to move ball by AddForce(). when I clicked.

```
private void MoveBall(Vector3 pos) 
{
    Ray HookRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(pos);
    int layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Block");
    RaycastHit objectHit;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    if (Physics.Raycast(HookRay, out objectHit, distance, layerMask))
    {
        moveTo = objectHit.point;
        Vector3 forceValue = moveTo - transform.position;
        forceValue.y = 0f;
        rb.AddForce( forceValue * charSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

[image]

And here is screenshot of Unity3D
I placed 3x1x3 cube blocks and arranged all positions Y to 0.
There are no cracks or gaps on it.

Comment: You have to show your code

Comment: Are the colliders of your additional blocks not lining up correctly? There may be small edges that cause the ball to pop into the air as it passes over them.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use one single block? You can *maybe* try using one collider object for all of your smaller blocks?

Comment: Thx buxter, but I want blocks falling randomly for makes a hole when the ball is passing through. that is why I made a small blocks on the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics and play with default contact offset, maybe make it much smaller like 0.00001 and try it. Another way you can freeze the y and then when some condition happens you can unfreeze it again.

Answer (score 0):

This likely comes from inaccuracies in the physics engine. They are there because the engine tries to cut corners to speed up processing. You can make it cut less counters (at the cost of speed) by following a few steps. First thing to try is to make the rigidbody do collision detection continuous. You can also try turning on interpolation. There are also more advanced ways where you will do physics updates more often than your frame rate. But I would try the simpler options first. They’re often enough.

Comment: Thx Adam, I tested all options for Interpolate, Collision Detection and Fixed Timestep but it's still jumping.

Comment: Hmm is it possible your ball is not round enough?